# tried to launch skyrim on steam using proton

Tags: wine, games, steam

```
Proton: Upgrading prefix from None to 8.0-104 (/media/kj7/BE3E36BB3E366D11/SteamLibrary/steamapps/compatdata/489830/)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kj7/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Proton - Experimental/proton", line 1766, in <module>
    g_session.init_session(sys.argv[1] != "runinprefix")
  File "/home/kj7/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Proton - Experimental/proton", line 1550, in init_session
    g_compatdata.setup_prefix()
  File "/home/kj7/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Proton - Experimental/proton", line 795, in setup_prefix
    os.symlink("../drive_c", self.prefix_dir + "/dosdevices/c:")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '../drive_c' -> '/media/kj7/BE3E36BB3E366D11/SteamLibrary/steamapps/compatdata/489830/pfx//dosdevices/c:'
/bin/sh\0-c\0/home/kj7/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=489830 -- /home/kj7/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/home/kj7/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/SteamLinuxRuntime_sniper'/_v2-entry-point --verb=waitforexitandrun -- '/home/kj7/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Proton - Experimental'/proton waitforexitandrun  '/media/kj7/BE3E36BB3E366D11/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Skyrim Special Edition/SkyrimSELauncher.exe'\0
chdir "/media/kj7/BE3E36BB3E366D11/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Skyrim Special Edition"
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/kj7/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/kj7/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/kj7/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/kj7/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/kj7/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Proton: Upgrading prefix from None to 8.0-104 (/media/kj7/BE3E36BB3E366D11/SteamLibrary/steamapps/compatdata/489830/)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kj7/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Proton - Experimental/proton", line 1766, in <module>
    g_session.init_session(sys.argv[1] != "runinprefix")
  File "/home/kj7/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Proton - Experimental/proton", line 1550, in init_session
    g_compatdata.setup_prefix()
  File "/home/kj7/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Proton - Experimental/proton", line 795, in setup_prefix
    os.symlink("../drive_c", self.prefix_dir + "/dosdevices/c:")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '../drive_c' -> '/media/kj7/BE3E36BB3E366D11/SteamLibrary/steamapps/compatdata/489830/pfx//dosdevices/c:'
Uploaded AppInterfaceStats to Steam
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1: Don't use NTFS

Wine uses a [colon in the pathname and symlinks](https://reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/ufmyuy/cannot_run_proton_steam_game_in_external_ntfs/), and [NTFS doesn't like it](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Proton/issues/5168). Move your games to your ext4 partition.

## Solution 2: Symlink your compatdata folder back

I adapted this from the [Proton wiki](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Proton/wiki/Using-a-NTFS-disk-with-Linux-and-Windows#preventing-ntfs-read-errors) to fit your setup. Run the following:

```bash
mkdir ~/.local/share/AskUbuntuSteamAppsCompatData
rm -rf /media/kj7/BE3E36BB3E366D11/SteamLibrary/steamapps/compatdata
ln -s ~/.local/share/AskUbuntuSteamAppsCompatData /media/kj7/BE3E36BB3E366D11/SteamLibrary/compatdata
```